# PHP and Ghostscript to convert a multipage PDF to a single JPG

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

For my website I use a little script to convert PDF to JPG.

```
exec('gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r150 -dJPEGQ=60 -sDEVICE=jpeg -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile= '.$file_name.' '.$pdf);
```

What i want is when I have a multipage PDF convert it to a single jpg (multipage in one jpg).

Somebody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Technically, this doesn't have anything to do with PHP, as it's purely a ghostscript operational problem.

Comment: Ok, but my question is still the same :)

Comment: @Leon van der Veen: Do I understand correctly -- you want the output JPEG to contain in 1 large image all the original PDF pages similar to an n-Up layout? Something like the `montage` subcommand of {Image,Graphics}Magick can achieve with multiple JPEG input files? -- Ghostscript cannot do that...

Comment: @Leon van der Veen: If you hope that 1 JPEG file can hold multiple pages like a multipage TIFF can do: no, this is not possible. For TIFF, its specification allows that; there is no analogous feature for JPEG....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to achieve this:

#### PDF input pages:

```
+---+  +---+  +---+ 
| a |  | b |  | c |
|   |  |   |  |   |
+---+  +---+  +---+ ...
```

(3 or more single pages)

#### JPEG output:

```
+---+
| a |
|   |
+...+
| b |
|   |
+...+
| c |
|   |
+...+
|   |
~~~~~
```

or this:

```
+---+---+---+~~ 
| a . b . c |
|   .   .   |
+---+---+---+~~ ...
```

or this:

```
+---+---+-~
| a . b . 
|   .   .
+...+...+~
| c .   
|   .   
+---+~~
```

or some other variation of single page JPEG...

Ghostscript cannot do that in a single step. However, you could achieve this in a two-step approach:

1. Use Ghostscript to do an n-up layout of the PDF.
2. (Or use some other software to create n-Ups from your PDF.)
3. Use Ghostscript to transform the n-up PDF to JPEG.

### 1. Using Ghostscript to create n-Up PDF pages

I'm not going to give a detailed instruction how to do that (it also depends on your exact output requirements.

However here are two links leading to SuperUser.com which explain the procedure in some detail. They will help you to set up your own steps:

- [Linux-based tool to chop PDFs into multiple pages](https://superuser.com/a/192293/40894)
- [Freeware to split a pdf's pages down the middle?](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894)

### 2. Using other tools to create n-Up PDFs

- [PDFJam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) includes the `pdfnup` utility
- [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sf.net/) includes the `podofoimpose` utility

### 3. Using Ghostscript to convert your new PDF to JPEG

You seem to know already how to do this...

Comment: How did you end up doing this? I'm trying to do the same thing and not sure how to do the first type of N-up combination.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall JPEG permitting multiple images in a single file. If it does, Ghostscript certainly doesn't, so the only way you could do this (with Ghostscript) would be to write your own device.

You could create a multiple page TIFF file, using JPEG compression instead, but Ghostscript doesn't support that either, but if you are writing your own device anyway.....